# Compute the spectral measure of an operator $(T\mathbf{a})_{n}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ on the space of square summable sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider the space $\mathcal{H}$ of square summable sequences $\mathbf{a}=\{a_{n}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$. The operator is defined by $$(T\mathbf{a})_{n}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}.$$

I want to compute the spectral resolution of this operator. From this website, https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Spectral_resolution, the spectrum measure $\mu$ can define resolution by $\mu((-\infty, t))$. So I guess the key is to get the spectral measure of this operator.

---

**Edit 1: I think I got at least the spectrum**

Given $\Psi\in\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, we can define $\hat{\Psi}\in L^{2}([0,2\pi))$ by $\hat{\Psi}(\xi):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{in\xi}\Psi_{n},$ with $$\Psi_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\xi}d\xi.$$

Then, the map $$U:\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow L^{2}([0,2\pi),\dfrac{d\xi}{2\pi}),\ \ \Psi\longrightarrow_{U}\hat{\Psi},$$ is unitary.

We want to know what does $UTU^{-1}$ give us. Take $f(\xi)\in L^{2}([0,2\pi))$, then $$(TU^{-1}f)(n)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{-i(n+1)\xi}-e^{-in\xi})f(\xi)d\xi=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-in\xi}(e^{-i\xi}-1)f(\xi)d\xi,$$ which implies that $$(UTU^{-1})(\xi)=(e^{-i\xi}-1)f(\xi).$$ Now we have the form of our operator in Fourier space, we are equipped to determine its spectrum.

Look at the resolvent:
\begin{align*}
R(T):=\{\lambda:(\lambda-T)\ \text{is invertible}\}&=\{\lambda:\lambda-e^{-i\xi}+1\neq 0\ \ \text{for all}\ \ \xi\in [0,2\pi)\}\\
&=\{\lambda:\lambda\neq e^{-i\xi}-1\ \ \ \text{for all}\ \ \xi\in [0,2\pi)\}\\
&=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{|\lambda+1|=1\}.
\end{align*}

This implies that the spectrum is $$\sigma(T)= \{|\lambda+1|=1\}.$$ We denote this set to be $\mathbb{S}_{1}^{*}(-1,1)$.

Am I correct?

---

**Edit 2: I possibly get the spectral measure. But it confuses me**

Now, for $f\in C(\mathbb{S}^{*}(-1,1))$ in Fourier space $f(T)$ is just multiplication by $f(e^{-i\xi}-1)$. Fix $\Psi\in\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, and let $\hat{\Psi}$ be the corresponding function in $L^{2}([0,2\pi))$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int f(T)d\mu_{\Psi}=\langle \Psi|f(T)\psi\rangle_{\ell^{2}}&=\langle U^{-1}U\Psi|f(T)U^{-1}U\Psi\rangle_{\ell{^2}}\\
&=\Big\langle U\Psi\Bigg|\Big(Uf(T)U^{-1}\Big)U\Psi\rangle_{L^{2}}\\
&=\langle \hat{\Psi}|f(e^{-i\xi}-1)\hat{\Psi}\rangle_{L^{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\overline{\hat{\Psi}}f(e^{-i\xi}-1)\hat{\Psi}d\xi\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{-i\xi}-1)|\hat{\Psi}(\xi)|^{2}d\xi.
\end{align*}

Write $\lambda:=e^{-i\xi}-1$, then $d\xi=\frac{d\lambda}{-e^{-i\xi}}$ and $\xi=i\log(\lambda+1)$ where $\log$ is taking over the principal branch (it's okay if just a general $\log$ since $\xi\in [0,2\pi]$). Then,
\begin{align*}
\int fd\mu_{\Psi}&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{S}_{1}^{*}(-1,0)}f(\lambda)|\hat{\Psi}(i\log(\lambda+1))|^{2}\dfrac{d\lambda}{-e^{-i\xi}},
\end{align*}
therefore, $$d\mu_{\Psi}=|\hat{\Psi}(i\log(\lambda+1))|^{2}\dfrac{d\lambda}{-e^{-i\xi}}\Bigg|_{\mathbb{S}_{1}^{*}(-1,0)}.$$

According to this website, https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Spectral_resolution, the spectrum measure $\mu$ can define resolution by $\mu((-\infty, t))$. But you see my spectrum density is restricted to the unit circle. I am not sure how to go back to the real line.

---

Are the above things correct? How can I proceed?

Comment: Hint: what does your operator look like under Fourier transform?

Comment: @Ruy Okay, I just edited the post.

Comment: @Ruy am I correct?

Comment: Yes.   The spectral measure of a **normal** operator is defined on its spectrum, which is contained in the real line only for **self-adjoint** operators.

Comment: I guess your definition of spectral measure is only suitable for self-adjoint operators and you should instead use the most general one:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure The problem is that the definition you propose is a bit like Stieltjes integral which only works on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Ruy I am sorry that I am a little bit confused. Do you mean I got the spectrum correct $\textbf{and}$ $d\mu_{\Psi}$ correct? But the definition of resolution is wrong, so I should change it? If $d\mu_{\Psi}$ was not correct, I read the wikipedia but I still don't quite get it, would you mind posting an answer? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition a *spectral resolution*  on a Hilbert space $H$,
defined on a measurable space $(X, \mathscr B)$, is a function
$$
  P:\mathscr B \mapsto  B(H),
  $$
such that

- $P(E)$ is a projection for each $E$ in $\mathscr B$,
- $P(\emptyset) = 0$, and $P(X) = I$,
- whenever $\{E_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a pairwise disjoint collection of measurable sets, one has that
  $$
    P\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}E_n\right) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N}P(E_n),
    $$
  the sum converging in the weak operator topology.

---

A well known form of the spectral theorem for bounded *normal* operators
asserts that, given any such operator $T$, there exists a spectral resolution $P$ defined on the Borel subsets of $\sigma (T)$ such
that
$$
  T=\int_{\sigma (T)} \lambda  \, dP(\lambda ).
  \tag 1
  $$
This integral is supposed to be interpreted in the weak sense, meaning that for every $\xi $ and $\eta $ in $H$, one
has that
$$
  \langle T\xi , \eta \rangle =\int_{\sigma (T)} \lambda  \, d P_{\xi , \eta }(\lambda ),
  $$
where $P_{\xi , \eta }$ is the actual (complex) measure on $\sigma (T)$, defined for every Borel set $E$ by
$$
  P_{\xi , \eta }(E)=  \langle P(E)\xi , \eta \rangle.
  $$

---

When $T$ is a self-adjoint operator, it is well known that $\sigma (T)\subseteq \mathbb R$, so its spectral resolution $P$ gives
rise to a so-called *cummulative distributiuon*, namely
$$
  \nu :t\in \mathbb R \mapsto  P(\sigma(T)\cap (-\infty ,t)) \in  B(H).
  $$
The importance of $\nu $ is that the integral in (1) can be expressed as a sort of Stieltjes integral
$$
  T=\int_{-\infty }^\infty  \lambda  \, d\nu (\lambda ).
  $$

For that reason, some authors prefer to emphasize $\nu $ over $P$, perhaps also because students have not yet learned any measure
theory at this point, but have already seen the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.  However I think  this is
not such a good idea because it has no counterpart for normal operators.

---

Finally,  if  $H=L^2(X, \mathscr B, \mu )$,  and $T$ is the so called multiplication operator defined on $H$ by
$$
  T(\xi )|_x = \varphi (x)\xi (x),  \quad \forall \xi \in  H,  \quad \forall x\in  X,
  $$
where $\varphi $ is a fixed bounded measurable complex valued function on $X$,  one may prove that the spectrum of $T$ is the essential range of
$\varphi $, and the spectral resolution provided by the spectral theorem is such that, for every $E\subseteq \sigma (T)$,
$P(E)$
is the orthogonal projection on the subspace $L_2(\varphi^{-1}(E))$.

---

Regarding the case in point,  we have that  $X=[0, 2π)$  and $φ(t) = e^{-it}+1$,  so the spectral resolution may be  obtained
as above.

Comment: Could you really compute the resolution? I don't see how I can compute it from above. I am sorry for my repeating confusion :((

Comment: $P(E)$ is the orthogonal projection on $L^2(F)$,  where $F=\{t∈ [0, 2π): e^{-it}+1∈ E\}$.

Comment: Yes, so this is where I don't get it. So we will use this to compute $P(E)$, but we are being abstract for a while, what is the orthogonal projection on such $L^{2}(F)$?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I am identifying $L^2(F)$ with the subspace of $L^2[0,2\pi)$ formed by the functions vanishing on $F\setminus [0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Yes. But how could I compute $P(E)$, like explicitly? Could you show me the computation details? Like, the explicit formula of this resolution? As you have put in so many works in this post, I will open an bounty for you tomorrow :))

Comment: A very concrete way to express the projection $P$ on $L^2(F)$ is simply
  $$
  P(\xi )|_x = 1_F(x)\xi (x),
  $$
  where $1_F$ is the characteristic function of $F$.

Comment: and That's it?? so basically as long as I got the spectrum, I will get $F$, and then I can say, the resolution is $$P(\xi)|_{x}=\mathbb{1}_{F}(x)\xi(x)$$ for $x\in X$ and $\xi\in H$?

Comment: I think this is all.

Comment: oh this is nice. By the way, is spectrum measure in my edit correct? Thank you so much :)) wait for the bounty. Many thanks !!!!

Comment: I didn't check the fine detail but it looks good.

Comment: nice. Thank you so much for your patient help.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Enough to get the spectrum of $T(e_n)= e_{n-1}$, where $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is the orthnormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$.  Now, $\mathcal{H}$ is isometric with $L^2(S^1)$ with the norm
$$f\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(e^{it}|^2 dt $$
with
$$e_n \mapsto \epsilon_n$$
with $\epsilon_n(t) = e^{i n t}$.
(this is the inverse Fourier transform)

Now, on the $L^2(S^1)$, $T$ becomes the map $\epsilon_{n}\mapsto \epsilon_{n-1}$, that is, the multiplication by the function $\epsilon_{-1}(t)= e^{-i t}$

Comment: Hello, can you expand on how you get the map $\epsilon_n\mapsto\epsilon_{n-1}$ and how to use this to get the spectral resolution? And how do you determine the spectral measure?

Comment: Hi I guess I have got the spectrum in the edit. I am not sure if I got the spectrum measure correct. If the spectrum measure is correct, what is the resolution?